# Cómo eliminar un dato de un array (pop) (javascript)

Tags: javascript, array, pop

estoy intentando eliminar datos a través de un array que yo mismo hice en el cual se añaden datos mientras yo les doy agregar a través de una tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo pueden observar ese botón de agregar me genera un array en el cual utilizo push para introducir cada dato uno por uno cada vez que hago click en el botón de agregar

tengo otra función que es para el botón de eliminar, donde me elimina la fila de la tabla, pero obviamente no lo hace en el array

tengo en mente dos cosas por el momento:

una opción es crear otro array de datos eliminados y mientras estoy pasando a guardar a la vez se eliminen los que están marcados en el array de los datos eliminados

otra opción que creo que es lo mejor es trabajar a través del mismo JavaScript con el botón de borrar para eliminar del único array que tengo los datos, quiero que ese botón simplemente me borre el dato del array seleccionado, pero creo que eso me dificulta un poco más y para lo que necesito ayuda

este es mi código que agrega hasta el momento

```
let placesArray = [];
        $('#btn-add').on('click', function () {
            let placeUrl = $('#place-url').val();
            let businessType = $('#business-types').select2('data');
            let duplicated = checkDuplicate(placeUrl);
            if ($('#place-form').valid() && !duplicated) {
                dataTable.row.add([
                    itemCounter,
                    placeUrl,
                    businessType[0].text,
                    '<button id="btn-remove-' + itemCounter + '" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs deleted" ' +
                    'data-id="' + itemCounter + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'
                ]).draw(false);
                itemCounter++;
                $('#place-url').val("");
                $("#business-types").val(null).trigger('change');

                let placeData = {
                    url: placeUrl,
                    businessTypeId: businessType[0].id
                };
                placesArray.push(placeData);
                $('#places').val(JSON.stringify(placesArray));
                console.log($('#places').val());
            } else if (duplicated) {
                $('#alert').show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#alert').hide();
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
```

y este es el código de la función del botón de borrado que de momento no le hace nada al array

```
$('#task-place-table tbody').on('click', '.deleted', function () {
                dataTable
                    .row($(this).parents('tr'))
                    .remove()
                    .draw();
            });
```

estaba pensando en usar pop, pero para eso debo ordenar el array para colocar el último array como el seleccionado, y aquí se me dificulta un poco la idea, gracias por leerme :)

Comment: Intenta usando `$(this).parent('tr')` ya que deberia esperar un unico elemento en `row()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas obtener uno de los valores desde la tabla y buscarlo para eliminar del arreglo:

- .closest('tr') se usa para acceder al elemento padre
- .find('td') para obtener todas las celdas
- .eq(1) para seleccionar la segunda
- .text() para obtener el valor a buscar

Ya con el valor, recorres el arreglo para buscarlo y, cuando lo encuentres, lo eliminas y finalizas el ciclo:

```
$('#task-place-table tbody').on('click', '.deleted', function () {
            // Obtener valor desde la segunda celda
            let value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();
            // Recorrer array para buscar valor
            for(let i = 0; i < placesArray.lengt; i++) {
                if(placesArray[i].url == value) {
                    // Se encontró valor, eliminar y salir del ciclo
                    placesArray.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Eliminar de dataTable
            dataTable
                .row($(this).parents('tr'))
                .remove()
                .draw();
});
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, seguramente funciona, pero no sé por qué colocar todo eso arriba me genera que el botón de borrado no funcione, y si intercambio el código hacia abajo (y lo del botón arriba) tampoco funciona. ni en el array ni los botones, no sé qué podría ser :/

Comment: Bro, sí está funcionando, pero no sé por qué el input que tengo no se actualiza, veré bien ese problema, debe ser por el orden de las variables en el resto de mis funciones, en un console.log sí las manda eliminadas con tu código, gracias!

Comment: qué tonto que soy, me faltó el stringify, ahora sí, muchas gracias!